# Is every wff of the following form the Skolemization of a closed formula in two-variable logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**Is every well-formed formula where arguments have the opposite handedness of their functions the Skolemization of a closed formula in two-variable logic?**

---

Let $\alpha^1, \alpha^2, \cdots$ be the left free variables. 
Let $\beta^1, \beta^2, \cdots$ be the right free variables. 
Let $g^1, g^2, \cdots$ be the left Skolem functions. 
Let $h^1, h^2, \cdots$ be the right Skolem functions. 
Let $c^1, c^2, \cdots$ be the neutral constants.

Neutral constants $c^1, c^2 \cdots$ are considered both left-handed and right-handed.

I think it's possible to Skolemize statements in [two-variable logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-variable_logic) in the following way. The variant of two-variable logic I'm considering has relation symbols $R^1, R^2, \cdots$ of any $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ arity and constant symbols but no positive arity function symbols. I also insist that the domain is non-empty *because I'm thinking about Skolemization and this assumption is convenient in the context of Skolemization*.

Let $i$ be the smallest fresh index.

$$ \frac{\forall x \mathop. \varphi}{\varphi[x := \alpha^i]} \;\text{for example}\; \frac{R^1(x, \alpha^1)}{R^1(\alpha^2, \alpha^1)} $$

$$ \frac{\forall y \mathop. \varphi}{\varphi[y := \beta^i]} $$

Let $j$ be the largest used index. Let $(\gamma^j)$ be an empty parameter list if $j$ is undefined.

$$ \frac{\exists x \mathop. \varphi}{\varphi[x := g^i(\beta^j)]} \;\text{for example}\; \frac{\exists x \mathop. R^1(x, g^1(\beta^1), g^1(\beta^2))}{R^1(g^2(\beta^2), g^1(\beta^1), g^1(\beta^2))} $$

$$ \frac{\exists y \mathop. \varphi}{\varphi[y := h^i(\alpha^j)]} \;\text{for example}\; \frac{\exists y \mathop. R^1(y)}{R^1(h^1())} $$

The above cases, together with the duality of existential and universal quantification (shown below).

Let $z$ be $x$ or $y$.

$$ \forall z \mathop. \varphi \;\;\text{is equivalent to}\;\; \lnot\exists z \mathop. \lnot \varphi $$

$$ \exists z \mathop. \varphi \;\;\text{is equivalent to}\;\; \lnot\forall z \mathop. \lnot \varphi $$

Using this fact, as well as the fact that we can hoist a $\forall$ or $\exists$ from the left or right branch from an expression headed by $\land$ or $\lor$, it is clear that we can *Skolemize* an arbitrary proposition in two-variable logic by repeatedly extracting quantifiers to the leftmost position and eliminating them by inserting free variables and Skolem functions.

I'm curious whether *any* quantifier-free formula subject to the conditions below is the Skolemization of *some* expression in two-variable logic (up to renumbering free variables and Skolem functions).

- All Skolem functions $g^\mathbb{N}, h^{\mathbb{N}}$ are nullary or unary.
- The argument to each unary Skolem function is a term of the opposite *handedness* (neutral constants $c^\mathbb{N}$ are both left-handed and right-handed).

Do these conditions describe exactly the quantifier-free expressions of two-variable logic that are the Skolemization of some closed expression in two-variable logic?

Answer (score 1):

No. And there's a straightforward counterexample.

$R^1(\alpha^1, \alpha^2, \alpha^3)$ does not break either of the rules listed in the question, but does not correspond to any closed formulas in two-variable logic. Any expression equivalent to it either requires free variables or requires three distinct variables to be universally bound in the same context.